# the type DataGrid doesn't support direct Content

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I am xaml and c# beginner i am across a situation in silverlight application that i got this error i am trying to create columns using xaml (i dont have to use c# or anything dynamic).

here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.ProgramGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    xmlns:dataprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="gridPrograms"
        Grid.Row="0"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListPrograms }"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}">
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="c1"
            Binding="{Binding Version}"
            Width="2*"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="c2"
            Binding="{Binding Live}"
            Width="2*"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="c3"
            Binding="{Binding DateCreation}"
            Width="2*"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Width="*"/>
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

And i get error : `the type DataGrid doesn't support direct Content`

EDIT:The problem was due to missing `<data:DataGrid.Columns>` that is solved but second problem is how to bind the column ?
Could someone please give me the solution  ? I mean i have to create columns using xaml only (not c#) and bind them. How to do that ?
thanks

Comment: Why do you need to declare the columns separately?

Comment: @Martin It will show the data seperately in seperate columns.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Do you want to have more than one `DataGrid` using the same column configuration?

Comment: @Martin Yes but with c# code in ViewModel and Model (as simple example as possible) . Please

Comment: I bet you mean **without** code...
And we won't need no code either: When you want to reuse a nicely configured `DataGrid` several times, the easiest thing to do is to put it inside a `UserControl` and just use that control throughout your xaml.

Comment: @Martin Ok, But how to do that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50877/discussion-between-user234839-and-martin)

Answer (score 3):

The message means you are not allowed to put anything between the opening and closing tags of the `DataGrid` as long as you are not "addressing" a `DataGrid` property, you are missing the opening tag `<data:DataGrid.Columns>`:

```
<data:DataGrid ...>
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
       ...
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: but how to do binding ? (could you please give me any sample for binding the columns) ?

Comment: I HAVE ADDED <data:DataGrid.Columns> first asked problem is solved but now have to do binding ?I mean i have to create columns using xaml only (not c#) and bind them. How to do that ?